# Bug with repository of visual templates in IDE Delphi 2010

Tags: ide, repository, delphi-2010

I am using Delphi 2010 . Three years ago I tried to use feature "Add to Repository" to create my own template of form . I chosen for it one unit with visual descendant of form and all was normal until I decided to make an icon for my this new template and have chosen a very unfortunate image file. It all has crashed. And since then I can't use visual templates normally at all. If click New->Other my IDE raises "Invalid image size"
error and does nothing. Fortunately I managed to avoid this problem partly through New->Customize and to set on first screen the ancestor form I want to inherit. But it of course additional difficulties especially when there are large amount of them and you need to do this operation often. I have been trying to find this my unfortunate template or it's image file in all possible places by all methods many times, but all in vain.
http://prntscr.com/wk9pum
http://prntscr.com/wk9orm

"SelectAny" is that my template. If I click on New-> [this item] it will show dialog for select directory beginning from root. If I select any directory it will copy the Delphi project that my form I put in template belong to and will swear on several unit files in it which were in another folder , not in the same as this project was.
I have so many things installed in my IDE and haven't any desire to reinstall it. Tell me please how i can get rid of that one curve template, find it and remove.

Comment: What exactly do you expect us to do here? We can't get access to your system to look around to see what you might have broken. It seems to me that your only option is to uninstall Delphi and reinstall it again to replace the repository.

Comment: I ask more accurately where these user templates are stored in IDE Delphi 2010 and have I any opportunity to drop them all ?

Comment: But as I could understand from your answer it's impossible or so difficult that to reinstall all would be easier

Comment: And that bug had gone by itself half a year later